# Calculator Program Issue

Tags: c

I am trying to work out why this program is not working. It is supposed to perform operations like

5 * 4 = 20     4 + 2 * 8 = 20           6/3 - 2 = 0.

However, things are not working.

Instructions are:

> Write a C program called calculate that performs simple arithmetic operations. The program takes 3 or 5 arguments from the command line.

I am not sure what to do now.

```
int calc(int x, char op, int y) {
    if (op == '+') {
        return (x+y);
    }
    if (op == '-') {
        return (x-y);
    }
    if (op == 't') {
        return (x*y);
    }
    if (op == '/') {
        return (x/y);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a,b,c,result,doOp;
    char op1, op2;

    if (argc == 4 || argc == 6) {
        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        b = atoi(argv[3]);
        op1 = *argv[2];
    } else {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments!");
        return 0;
    }

    if (argc == 6) {
        c = atoi(argv[5]);
        op2 = *argv[4];

        if ((op1 == '+' || op1 == '-') && (op2 == '/' || op2 == 't')) {
            result = calc(a, op1, calc(b, op2, c));
            printf("%d", result);
        }

        if ((op2 == '+' || op2 == '-') && (op1 == '/' || op1 == 't')) {
             result = calc((calc(a, op1, b)), op2, c);
             printf("%d", result);
        } else {
             result = calc((calc(a, op1, b)), op2, c);
             printf("%d", result);
        }
    }

    if (argc == 4) {
        result = calc(a, op1, b);
        printf("%d", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "things are not working!" - is not sufficient. What *does* this do, what debugging efforts have you undertaken thus far, and what are the results of those efforts ?. As far as potential bugs are concerned, `(x/y)` in `calc` is performing *integer* division, meaning, it will truncate remainder, leaving no fractional result. That function should also warn about not all code paths specify return value, and though that is possibly not logistically applicable to you if your input is successfully parsed, you never actually validate your input anyway, so its pure gambling with undefined behavior.

Comment: The `if` and `else` statements in `main` are structured incorrectly. If the `if ((op1 == '+' || op1 == '-') && (op2 == '/' || op2 == 't'))` is true, it executes the statement there but also executes the statement in the `else`. The `if` following it should be `else if`. (Alternatively, they can be restructured to reduce the cases.) Aside from that, show test cases that are failing, including the output you see and the output you expect from a working program.

Comment: When `argc == 6` you have two `if` statements and an `else`. All you need is the first `if` and the `else`. The second `if` does exactly the same thing as the `else`, so it's not needed.

Comment: Should "`4 + 2 * 8 = 20`" be `4 + 2 t 8 = 20`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Alireza.
The problems are several, but the main one was the missing "else" in your check to see which calculator sequencing to use.

```
int calc(int x, char op, int y) {

    if (op == '+') {
        return (x+y);
    }
    if (op == '-') {

        return (x-y);
    }
    if (op == 't') {

        return (x*y);
    }
    if (op == '/') {
        return (x/y);
    }

    printf("Unknown operator!"); // added error check
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int a,b,c,result,doOp;
    char op1, op2;

    if (argc == 4 || argc == 6) {

        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        b = atoi(argv[3]);
        op1 = *argv[2];

    } else {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments!");
        return 0;
    }

    if (argc == 6) {
        c = atoi(argv[5]);
        op2 = *argv[4];

        if ((op1 == '+' || op1 == '-') && (op2 == '/' || op2 == 't')) {

            result = calc(a, op1, calc(b, op2, c));
            printf("%d", result);
        }
        // added else if
        else if ((op2 == '+' || op2 == '-') && (op1 == '/' || op1 == 't')) {

            result = calc((calc(a, op1, b)), op2, c);
            printf("%d", result);
        }
        else {
            result = calc((calc(a, op1, b)), op2, c);
            printf("%d", result);
        }
    }

    if (argc == 4) {

        result = calc(a, op1, b);
        printf("%d", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```